# Is it possible to change the back color of all the forms from a single form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to change the back color of all the forms from a single form? Like in my system I have 10 forms and from a button click in a certain form can I change the back color of all the other form and save the color?

Comment: Yes you can, how do you create a new form?

Comment: help me please :) in the main menu there is a button called "change the theme" and when i click that i want to apply the defined color (for simplicity let's assume dark blue.) so i want to apply the dark blue colour to all the forms in my system. how can i do that?

Comment: Question stays, how are you instantiating the forms? Are you keeping their references in a list? You can do it on form_load event as well, but for already running forms, you must have their references to update them.

Comment: You can take Sagar's answer even further and create a static form manger. Each form would register itself there and then th manager could do all the work.. If you derive your forms from a common ancestor the registering would be coded only once in the base form, and the manager could be used for other tasks as well, like finding or ordering forms..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking Sagar's answer even further create a **static form manager**.

Each form would **register** itself there and then the manager can do all the work..

In the constructors register the forms:

```
public Form1()
{
    FormManager.registerForm(this);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

and in the `Closed` events **unregister**:

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    FormManager.unRegisterForm(this);
}
```

Now when you want to you can change all forms' `BackColors` like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormManager.setAllBackcolors(Color.Green);
}
```

Here is a minimal form manager class:

```
public static class FormManager
{

    private static List<Form> formList = new List<Form>();

    public static void registerForm(Form form)
    {
        if (!formList.Contains(form)) formList.Add(form);
    }

    public static void unRegisterForm(Form form)
    {
        if (formList.Contains(form)) formList.Remove(form);
    }


    public static void setAllBackcolors(Color backColor)
    {
        foreach (Form f in formList) if (f != null) f.BackColor = backColor;
    }

}
```

If you derive your forms from a common ancestor the registering & unregistering would be coded only once in the base form.

Of course the manager can be used for other tasks as well, like finding or ordering forms..

If you want to affect newly opening forms you can store the color in the manager and add a line to the register method..

Answer (score 1):

For this you can define one `static` variable in global class for back color and change it on button click.

Eg. On your each form code will be something like this ..

```
Form1.BackColor = globalClass.BackColor;
```

In GlobalClass.cs :

```
public static string BackColor="Red";
```

On your button click of certain form :

```
globalClass.BackColor = "Black";
```

This is one possible way of doing it.

You can apply your logic accordingly.

Comment: Each form also could use the same global color to initialze its own color when opening..

Comment: but he wants one button click of particular form to change the color

Comment: No already opened forms can not change their colors through this methods as its not web application

Comment: where to put this? Form1.BackColor = globalClass.BackColor;